# Binding to model that contains collections in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, collections, caliburn.micro

I am getting started with MVVM (using Caliburn.Micro) and have come across an issue which I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. I have a model `MediaCacherConfig` which represents a textfile that stores the data in json format. The model contains 2 lists of strings and one string by itself.

What I am struggling with is how to correctly set up the viewmodel and in particular the `AddNewFolder()` method. I'm not sure if I am raising the correct event and whether the viewmodel's representation is correct. I can see how to bind to a simple property, but binding to a collection seems a bit more of a head spinner as I am creating a whole new collection everytime an item (string) is added.

Furthermore, when I load an entirely new model I have to run the NotifyPropertyChanged() method on all the properties which doesn't make sense to me.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

```
public class MediaCacherConfig : IConfig
{

    public string DatabaseFileName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<string> FoldersToScan { get; set; }

    public ICollection<string> ExtensionsToIgnore { get; set; }

}
```

I have a viewmodel `MediaCacherConfigViewModel`:

```
    public class MediaCacherConfigViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{

    private MediaCacherConfig Model { get; set; }

    public string DatabaseFileName
    {
        get { return Model.DatabaseFileName; }
        set
        {
            Model.DatabaseFileName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DatabaseFileName);
        }
    }

    public BindableCollection<string> FoldersToScan
    {
        get
        {
            return new BindableCollection<string>(Model.FoldersToScan);
        }
        set
        {
            Model.FoldersToScan = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FoldersToScan);
        }
    }

    public BindableCollection<string> ExtensionsToIgnore
    {
        get
        {
            return new BindableCollection<string>(Model.ExtensionsToIgnore);
        }
        set
        {
            Model.ExtensionsToIgnore = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ExtensionsToIgnore);
        }
    }

    /* Constructor */
    public MediaCacherConfigViewModel()
    {
        LoadSampleConfig();
    }

    /* Methods */
    public void LoadSampleConfig()
    {

        MediaCacherConfig c = new MediaCacherConfig();

        string sampleDatabaseFileName = "testing.config";

        List<string> sampleFoldersToScan = new List<string>();
        sampleFoldersToScan.Add("A");
        sampleFoldersToScan.Add("B");
        sampleFoldersToScan.Add("C");

        List<string> sampleExtensionsToIgnore = new List<string>();
        sampleExtensionsToIgnore.Add("txt");
        sampleExtensionsToIgnore.Add("mov");
        sampleExtensionsToIgnore.Add("db");
        sampleExtensionsToIgnore.Add("dat");

        c.DatabaseFileName = sampleDatabaseFileName;
        c.FoldersToScan = sampleFoldersToScan;
        c.ExtensionsToIgnore = sampleExtensionsToIgnore;

        Model = c;

        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DatabaseFileName);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FoldersToScan);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ExtensionsToIgnore);


    }

    public void AddNewFolder()
    {
        Model.FoldersToScan.Add("new one added");
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FoldersToScan);

    }

    public void SaveConfig()
    {
        ConfigTools.Configure(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "Cacher", "Config"));

        ConfigTools.SaveConfig(Model,"sampleconfig.txt");              
    }

    public void LoadConfig()
    {
        ConfigTools.Configure(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "Cacher", "Config"));

        MediaCacherConfig m = ConfigTools.LoadConfig<MediaCacherConfig>("sampleconfig.txt") as MediaCacherConfig;
        Model = m;


        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DatabaseFileName);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FoldersToScan);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ExtensionsToIgnore);

    }
}
```

And here is my view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MediaCacher.Views.MediaCacherConfigView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="413" Width="300">
<Grid MinWidth="300" MinHeight="300" Background="LightBlue" Margin="0,0,0,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="409*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox x:Name="DatabaseFileName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,64,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="280" Height="42" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="FoldersToScan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="145" Margin="10,111,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="ExtensionsToIgnore" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="145" Margin="10,261,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="280"/>
    <Button x:Name="AddNewFolder" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Height="49"/>
    <Button x:Name="LoadConfig" Content="Load" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" Height="49"/>
    <Button x:Name="SaveConfig" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="203,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="87" Height="49"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here you are returning a brand new collection every time, so obviously nothing gets persisted.

```
 public BindableCollection<string> FoldersToScan
    {
        get
        {
            return new BindableCollection<string>(Model.FoldersToScan);
        }
        set
        {
            Model.FoldersToScan = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FoldersToScan);
        }
    }
```

Secondly, your AddFolder method should belong in your ViewModel. When you Add a string to your already existing collection the fact that it is a BindingCollection should fire off an event to your View automatically that a new Item was added.

---

This is how I would do it. This is obviously an example for demonstration purposes, please add everything else you need. Youd ideall want to pass `EventArgs` and note I am not implementing `INotifyPorpertyChanged` because I don't have time to write it all out. Also I am using `ObservableCollection` but you can use your `BindableCollection`.

The point of this example is to show you how to manage your ViewModel - > Model communcation. Technically speaking your View -> ViewModel should talk through a CommandPattern.

```
public class YourViewModel
    {
        private readonly YourModel model;
        private ObservableCollection<string> foldersToScan = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        public ObservableCollection<string> FoldersToScan
        {
            get { return this.foldersToScan; }
        }

        public YourViewModel(YourModel model)
        {
            this.model = model;
            this.model.OnItemAdded += item => this.foldersToScan.Add(item);
        }

        public void AddFolder(string addFolder) //gets called from view
        {
            this.model.AddFolder(addFolder); //could be ICommand using Command Pattern
        }
    }

    public class YourModel
    {
        private readonly List<string> foldersToScan;
        public IEnumerable<string>  FoldersToScan
        {
            get { return this.foldersToScan; }
        }


        public event Action<string> OnItemAdded; 

        public YourModel()
        {
            this.foldersToScan = new List<string>();
        }

        public void AddFolder(string folder)
        {
            this.foldersToScan.Add(folder);
            this.RaiseItemAdded(folder);
        }

        void RaiseItemAdded(string folder)
        {
            Action<string> handler = OnItemAdded;
            if (handler != null) handler(folder);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would you propose feeding through changes for the BindableCollection from the view->viewmodel->model?

Comment: theoretically your model should have a BindableCollection as well and your ViewModel just returns model.FoldersToScan. If not, in your add folder you can add your item to model.FoldersScan and raise an event of your list changing then add them to your viewmodel list.

Comment: @Peter i have added some sample code. It is very simplifying and is used just to give you an idea.